# One long If condition vs. many smaller conditions with checkpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, if-statement, theory

**TLDR: What is better: a long `if...else` that has lots of similar code throughout each of the conditions or many smaller `if...else` statements with multiple checkpoints.**

This is a question that may extend to many languages, but JavaScript is where I am applying this idea immediately.

In optimizing my JS, I have come across one massive `if...else` condition. Both the `if` and the `else` share some code where they execute a certain function based on a variable determined by the condition and then continue on to condition-specific functions. Here's an *example*:

```
var w  = $(window).width();

if (w > 1024) {

    var ww        = w/2;
    $(".container").width(ww);

    foo(); // represents long, in-common set of functions

    var imgWidth  = ww/3;
    $(".container img").width(imgWidth);

} else {

    var ww        = w/3;
    $(".container").width(ww);

    foo(); // represents long, in-common set of functions

    var imgWidth  = ww/4;
    $(".container img").width(imgWidth);

}
```

`foo()` representing a common midpoint/checkpointfunction that may be irrelevant to the value of the variables being declared but is essentially dependent upon them being executed. In my actual code, the `foo()` represents many common functions happening consecutively, forcing me to either write one massive `if...else` or many smaller checks along the way. My question is, is this a better/faster way:

```
var w  = $(window).width();

if (w > 1024) {

    var ww        = w/2;
    $(".container").width(ww);

} else {

    var ww        = w/3;
    $(".container").width(ww);
}

foo(); // represents a checkpoint with long, in-common sets of functions

if (w > 1024) {

    var imgWidth  = ww/3;
    $(".container img).width(imgWidth);

} else {

    var imgWidth  = ww/4;
    $(".container img).width(imgWidth);

}
```

Visually, I understand this to be a competition between these two models:
[image]

I understand either may create a larger file size if these functions get complex and have many common checkpoints, but performance is valued far more here than a few extra bytes. What's better (faster)?

Comment: There is no direct relationship between the length of the code you write and the performance of that code; The number of bytes in a code file will not help or hurt your application's performance.

Comment: @Zack yep, that's what I explaining in the first sentence of the closing paragraph - while also explaining that file size and redundancy are things that are not to be omitted.

Comment: While generally true, excessively large code size could start to lead to increased icache misses. It's generally not a problem in practice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By performance you mean processor-performance? The difference between the two cases will not be within measurement error, considering various Javascript engine JIT techniques, processor branch prediction, etc. Option B naively has more branches, but this does not necessarily impact performance. Design your code for human readability, and don't worry about the performance differences until your profiler is telling you that section of code is a problem.

Comment: So you're saying that, ultimately, the performance is something that won't be effected to a measurable extent even in a case where either of these options are exaggerated?

Comment: What makes you think that performance would be effected? Exaggerated how? If you are worried about the execution time of the conditional -- say it's an expensive computation that takes 200ms -- you can evaluate the conditional once and re-use the result. If you are worried about the mere act of branching, that is one CPU instruction. Modern hardware with branch prediction will essentially eliminate that instruction (e.g. both branches will provisionally execute in parallel). Even if you go to hundreds of if/else blocks, it will not rise above noise in performance metrics.

Answer (score 2):

The only condition you care about is whether or not the width is `> 1024` which only determines the divisor. You could get rid of all but one condition (a ternary, in my example) and do this:

```
var w  = $(window).width();
// condition to get the divisor
var divisor = w > 1024 ? 2 : 3;
var ww = ww/divisor;

$(".container").width(ww);
foo();
$(".container img").width(ww/(divisor+1));
```

Comment: This would be a good solution to the exact example above, but my question is asking whether or not long if conditions are better than many conditions with similar midpoints.

Comment: @JLF I understand that, but my solution is really trying to provide an example that: frequently (not always), long sets of `if/else` statements can be boiled down to a simpler solution. Regarding your overarching question, It is better to accomplish any logic dependent on the condition within one block, as adding redundant conditionals are a computational waste.

Comment: Not only are the redundant conditionals a computational waste, they also make the code harder to read and understand.

Comment: @tsleyson but what if there are large blocks of code in between two condition-specific blocks, would creating a checkpoint not improve its readability as it would be reminding the reader what is being determined? We are considering very long blocks of code here, not something as the very simple instance above.

Comment: @JLF I favor factoring out as much of it as possible. If you really, really, really, really can't avoid this dichotomy, I find the redundant code inside the conditionals more readable since the structure more obviously suggests what's going on. But you didn't really ask about readability, so I just left a comment.

Comment: @tsleyson readability ultimately became the answer to this question... as the other answers suggest that neither way is measurably more efficient than the other lol

Answer (score 2):

I am only giving this as an answer because I think it will run past 500 characters. Since you have just given a synthetic example, the answer is a big "it depends."

The benefit of two single large blocks would be that the cost of performing the check only happens a single time, although you could just as easily throw the value into a boolean at the beginning and then your checks are probably costless  in the bigger context, provided this is not terribly hot code (i.e. not itself being executed constantly) and you don't have a ton of checks.

The benefit of multiple checks is probably in code maintenance, specifically that you, or your successor, will not need to worry about updating the same code in both branches. Although factoring out some of the code into separate functions might offer the same sort of benefit. Again if this is hot code you might find the function calls too costly, but I suspect probably not.

I would focus on what will be most maintainable, which I would suggest means either multiple checks or factoring out some code. I would not worry terribly about performance unless it is an issue - avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

First focus on readability/maintenance. When you have clear code, identifying performance bottlenecks will be easier.
As @Rob suggested, the current example can be simplified. When that's not the case, you should consider how much the logic in the if-blocks are similar.
When they are about similar, you can use a function for them.

```
var w  = $(window).width();
set_container_using_width(w);
foo(); // represents a checkpoint with long, in-common sets of functions
set_img_using_width(w);
```

The code reads like a novel: you want to call foo() and have some minor differences depending on w.
When the blocks/logic are really different, the novel should say: I tell you about two different adventures, in which both heroes take a voyage with a train (train implemented by foo()).

```
var w  = $(window).width();
if (w > 1024) {
   do_some_strange_calls();
   foo(); // represents long, in-common set of functions
   do_more_strange_calls();
} else {
   some_normal_calls();
   foo();
   some_more_normal_calls();
}
```

This code can be simplified into

```
var w  = $(window).width();
if (w > 1024) {
   foo_wrapper_strange_handling();
} else {
   foo_wrapper_normal_handling();
}
```

When the if-statemant changes (new requirements, `if (w>2048)`) you want to change it at 1 line.
The following code is less clear (difficult to maintain):

```
var w  = $(window).width();
if (w > 1024) {
   do_some_strange_calls();
} else {
   some_normal_calls();
}

foo(); // represents long, in-common set of functions

if (w > 1024) {
   do_more_strange_calls();
} else {
   some_more_normal_calls();
}
```